# Migrate logs from Stackdriver to Grafana Loki

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, grafana-loki

I am planning on migrating from Stackdriver as it is costly and the logs management isn't that clear, therefore I am going to implement Loki (Canary+Loki+Grafana).

My question is:

How do I migrate my logs from Stackdriver to Loki? Do I need to implement a shipping tool to collect the logs and send them to Grafana Loki?

If that's the case, please provide me with advices regarding this matter :))

**Environment:**

Kubernetes: 1.21.14-gke.4300

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a log shipping tool to collect logs from your kubernetes cluster and send them to loki. Use a [Fluentd log collector](https://isitobservable.io/observability/kubernetes/how-to-collect-logs-with-fluentd) which can forward to loki.

You can configure Fluentd to pull logs from Stackdriver; it has a plugin for Stackdriver which will collect logs and forward them to the other destinations.
Now configure Fluentd to push logs to loki and it also has a plugin for Loki that can forward logs. You need to configure it with the Loki endpoint and credentials. For Loke please check the [official page](https://www.fluentd.org/plugins/all) for plugins and more [information](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/fluentd/).

There are many other tools like Fluentd where you can search it on Google.com. If your complexity is more you can use [Google Cloud Operation Suite](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs) where you can integrate more for managing logs and metrics.